# cv2.imshow() doesn't update

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I want to stream a thermal image on python, but I only get one image that doesn't update. The thermal sensor stops updating the temperature. When I remove the cv2.imshow, everything works fine again. The thermal sensor prints the current temperature again. I've tried a lot of other options, like `plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.BGR2RGB))
plt.show()` or what I commented below in my code, but nothing seemed to work.
See below my code:

```
import socket
import pickle
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

HEADERSIZE = 8355

host = ''
port = 1238

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

while True:

    full_msg = b''
    new_msg = True
    while True:
        msg = s.recv(8355)
        if new_msg:
            print(f"new message length: {msg[:HEADERSIZE]}")
            msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
            new_msg = False

        full_msg += msg

        if len(full_msg) - HEADERSIZE == msglen:
            print("Full msg recvd")
            print(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])

            d = pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
            print(d)

            image = np.array(d)
            image = cv2.resize(image, (300, 300))
            print(image)
            plt.imsave('color_img1.jpg', image)
            img = cv2.imread('color_img1.jpg', 1)

            #plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
            #plt.show()
            #cv2.imshow('lmao', img)
            #cv2.waitKey(0)

            new_msg = True
            full_msg = b''

    print(full_msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the waitKey input value compatible with your sensor frame rate. For example if you get the new image every 100 ms, you should feed waitKey with an input less than 100 ms:

```
cv2.imshow('lmao', img)
cv2.waitKey(10) # almost always 10 miliseconds is good enough for showing a good image
```

Comment: ahhh, I didn't know about that. Thank you so much!